# Migrating from Netbeans to VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm migrating from Netbeans to VSCode, and after some time of use, I don't understand how can I see all my projects into the navigator so I can work in some project I need and sometimes copy files between projects too. Actually, I've just can open some folder or I can just open the root folder of all my projects, okay, but with it, I can't sync each project with some FTP server using the third-party ftp-simple plugin for FTP connections.

This is vscode Version: 1.37.1 using macos.

Comment: i'm a little overwhelmed too, 1.74.2. Would never migrate from Netbeans if I knew how to safely try GraalVM without messing all the javas on my old machine